# Got an error showing invalid index, size is zero on eclipse while developing for android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Got an error showing invalid index, size is zero on eclipse and failed to open on emulator.

Here is my mainactivity code and logcat error.

```
`package com.example.notetakingapp;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.notetakingapp.data.NoteDataSource;
import com.example.notetakingapp.data.NoteItem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private NoteDataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dataSource=new NoteDataSource(this);
        List<NoteItem> notes= dataSource.findAll();
        NoteItem note=notes.get(0);
        note.setText("updated!!!");
        dataSource.update(note);
        notes=dataSource.findAll();
        note=notes.get(0);
        Log.i("NOTES", note.getKey() + ": " + note.getText());

    }`
```

**Logcat:**

```
11-21 19:06:59.463: E/Trace(5216): error opening trace file: No such file or directory   (2)
11-21 19:07:00.323: D/AndroidRuntime(5216): Shutting down VM
11-21 19:07:00.323: W/dalvikvm(5216): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.notetakingapp/com.example.notetakingapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at com.example.notetakingapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-21 19:07:00.343: E/AndroidRuntime(5216):     ... 11 more
11-21 19:07:03.163: I/Process(5216): Sending signal. PID: 5216 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Your `collection` is empty this is reason why you are getting `Exception`. Before manipulating with items you need to check if `collection` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

If size is 0 then there are no items, so you have to check that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dataSource=new NoteDataSource(this);
    List<NoteItem> notes= dataSource.findAll();
    if(notes.size() > 0)
    {
        NoteItem note=notes.get(0);
        note.setText("updated!!!");
        dataSource.update(note);
        notes=dataSource.findAll();
        note=notes.get(0);
        Log.i("NOTES", note.getKey() + ": " + note.getText());
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

datasource is initialized but not assigned. That might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The method `dataSource.findAll()` is probably returning nothing.

You are trying to access the List index 0. At index 0 is the first element of you List, but if it is empty there is no element at index 0, and that's when you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

You could add a condition to check is the List is empty or not:

```
if(notes.size() > 0) {
  //operations
} else {
  //List is empty message
}
```